# Website running slow in IE with no specific reason why

Tags: performance, internet-explorer

We have a [website](http://www.playforce.co.uk) that a few people are complaining about it running extremely slow. We're struggling to figure out why and to even recreate it. Most are mentioning that it's running slow in IE.

It's not limited to any specific section of the site, just the whole thing in general.

There's been several developers creating/adjusting the code so it's overly bloated but we can't see any specific reason why this should happen.

Can anyone see why?

We've also run a speed test:

[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't here to provide you with free performance auditing of your work. Your question as it stands is too vague and broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running a profiling test with IE on your website and there is a call to:

`http://www.playforce.co.uk/-ms-transform.htc`

Which is giving `error 404` not found and taking 1 second to complete (0.91 sec).

If is found all around your css under this line:

```
behavior:url(-ms-transform.htc);
```

Answer (score 0):

***Am no expert !! Am welcome to better suggestion and corrections of what i am about to say***

You can try using a trial version of [Borland Silk meter](https://silkwebmeter.borland.com/) ..

They tend to measure the speed with which each element loads using various browsers and various geographical locations which are configurable by you.

Also , since only some of the user's are complaining about the speed being an issue you should also check the speed of their internet and their browser version and other addon etc of those users. Because sometimes the problem is not only with the server .

Try the above tool to confirm nothing is wrong in your server and then proceed to checking the client's browser and network.